# JointTrajectoryAction position vs /joint_state positions

Tags: ros, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to replay a saved trajectory by using the joint_states positions and JointTrajectoryAction. However, for some of the joints (upper arm roll), the /joint_state accumulates all the movement, so its position is some arbitrarily large number (let's say 600).  However, JointTrajectoryAction seems to work on a different frame, because if I issue a goal to position 600, it ends up spinning indefinitely despite the /joint_state claiming it's very close to 600.  How do the joint_positions differ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50993/jointtrajectoryaction-position-vs-/joint_state-positions/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2012-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out that the JointTrajectoryAction automatically normalizes the given input between -pi and pi. Normalizing 600 to something between -pi and pi fixed this problem.

---

Originally posted by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) with karma: 52 on 2012-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0